# How to increase a for loop sequentially

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have written a crawler for multipage. It works when pages increase like: 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. However, trouble comes up when it increases sequentially like: 0, 120, 240, 360 and so on. I am stuck at this point. Hope somebody out there to provide me with a workaround. What I'm up to with my code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()
for page in range(120):
    driver.get("https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/eld?s={0}".format(page))
    for title in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("hdrlnk"):
        print (title.text)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range()` accepts 3 arguments: start, stop and step. You should try

```
for page in range(0, 1200, 120)
```

This should get you `0`, `120`, `240`, `360`...`1080`

Let me know if it's not what you're looking for

Comment: No way!!! Sir Andersson, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a trillion.